# Using HTML 5's localStorage in ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, local-storage

I have a store in ExtJS which stores data in JSON format. I want to copy this data into HTML 5's local storage.

```
localStorage["bar"] = jsonData;
```

What kind of changes I need to make or library I have to include in my ExtJs 4 application to utilize HTML 5 features.

Thanks

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, [localStorage isn't an HTML 5 feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the LocalStorage proxy? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

It allows you to treat model data in the typical ExtJS fashion, but uses LocalStorage as the persistence layer.